# I cannot start my nestjs project after a reboot

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs

I don't know what happened prior to this issue but after each reboot i have to fully remove npm and nodejs, reinstall both npm and nodejs in order to start my nestjs project.

After rebooting running the npm run start command in my nestjs project, npm stops halfway and exits without any error codes (Link below of the terminal output).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrbXp.png

What could it be? Is there perhaps some system path that gets wiped on reboot?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: check if you have same process running in background

Answer (score 0):

Turns out both my angular project and my nestjs project required me to run a very specific version of node. anything else resulted in a silently crashing nestjs application with no errors.

For anyone stumbling into the same problem try fiddling around with the node version you're running

```
npm install -g n
n 10
```